# Odoo 15 ubl_bis3.xml [BR-CL-23]-Unit code MUST be coded according to the UN/ECE Recommendation 20 with Rec 21 extension

Tags: odoo, peppol

Some of our ubl_bis3.xml invoices generated with Odoo 15 are rejected when we try to send them over an Peppol access point. We get the following error:

```
[BR-CL-23]-Unit code MUST be coded according to the UN/ECE Recommendation 20 with Rec 21 extension
```

that is due to a deprecated translation of the unit **km** to

```
<cbc:InvoicedQuantity unitCode="KTM"
```

When we change the deprecated unitCode manually in the xml file to "KMT" which is the [official PEPPOL BIS Billing 3.0 unitCode](https://docs.peppol.eu/poacc/billing/3.0/rules/BR-CL-23/)  the invoices are accepted.

When we try to update this translation rule in the code of the account_edi module this does not work.
We changed it in the account_edi/models/uom.py the following line to the correct value:

```
            'uom.product_uom_km': 'KMT',
```

but even after updating the account_edi module the generated xml files still keep the old "KTM" translation.
Where could we adapt the code so that the correct translation is used?